# Compiling ARM .s file on Mac

Tags: macos, assembly, compilation, arm, gnu

I am on Mac Os X and I am having trouble compiling a .s ARM assembly file.
my .s file is this:

```
mov r0, r1
```

just to see if it works.
but when i do 
`arm-elf-as my.s`
i get an 
`a.out` file.
i do 
`chmod +x a.out`
and 
`./a.out`
but it says 
`cannot execute binary file`

this has me confused, because it should be able to execute if i compiled it with arm-elf-as. How do i go about compiling this .s?

Comment: You need an ARM processor (or an emulator) with the right operating system to run your ARM binary.

Comment: I think you need to clarify, are you trying to execute an ARM file on a Mac? A Mac does not run ARM binaries, just x86 binaries (and possibly PowerPC binaries using Rosetta)

Comment: If i want to do assembly on Mac Os X should i use nasm, as, or what compiler?

Answer (score 4):

You're assembling it allright, you just can't run it on a Mac since Macs don't have ARM CPUs. If you install Xcode with iOS support, you can compile ARM code:

```
# the file
$ cat foo.s
    mov r0, r1

# compile with llvm-gcc
$ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -c foo.s

# resulting file is ARM object file
$ file foo.o
foo.o: Mach-O object arm

# and you can disassemble it
$ otool -v -t foo.o
foo.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
00000000    e1a00001    mov r0, r1
```

You won't be able to run anything, because for that you'll need a runtime system and and ARM  CPU. You can use `-isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk` or similar to compile for the iPhoneOS for example.