# Compiling ARM on Mac for iOS

Tags: iphone, macos, assembly, arm, jailbreak

This is a bit similar to [Compiling ARM .s file on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150909/compiling-arm-s-file-on-mac)

Especially the response given by Simon Urbanek, thanks for that!

I'm basically wondering how to make this asm file work on a jailbroken iPhone.  Currently, I am cross compiling and attempting to place the object on the iPhone and run it without success because its not meant for the iPhoneOS obviously, its just ARM code with no Mach-O header.  Any idea how to get this working?  -isysroot may be the answer, but I've provided the SDK file as its input and I don't get a mach-o header.

Also, I would also love to know if there is a way to compile ASM code on the iphone itself without using inline gcc.

Anyways, here is the current workflow:

## [On Mac]

```
$ cat foo.s
mov r0, r1

$/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -c foo.s

$ file foo.o
foo.o: Mach-O object arm

$ otool -v -t foo.o
foo.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
00000000    e1a00001    mov r0, r1
```

## [On iPhone]

```
$ file foo.o
foo.o: Mach-O object arm

$ otool -v -t foo.ofoo.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
00000000    e1a00001    mov r0, r1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to compile the code, you also have to *link* it to produce an executable from the object code:

```
$/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 foo.o -o foo
$./foo
```

If you omit the C/C++ part of this, and start right from the assembly step, you can use this document for understanding:
http://markuskimius.wikidot.com/programming:explain:compiling

Comment: Correct, yes I forgot that step, but at this point it would still be a malformed mach-o file since there is no header.  the code simply looks like this:  __text:00000000 ; Segment type: Pure code
__text:00000000                 AREA __text, CODE, READWRITE, ALIGN=0
__text:00000000                 CODE32
__text:00000000                 MOV     R0, R1
__text:00000000 ; __text        ends
__text:00000000
__text:00000000                 END

Comment: Well, if you link it, then it should be correct... Have you just TRIED running it without trying to figure out sceptically the exact binary representation of a file? Also have a look at here for what and when a header's needed: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html